# Matrix Inverse in Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, matrix, pagerank

Actually I am trying to implement PageRank Algorithm in Swift. I am using [Swix](https://github.com/stsievert/swix) and Accelerate framework.Actually for getting the pageRank I need to solve Linear Equation.I am trying to do this by taking the Inverse of the matrix.Then multiply the Inverse with some other matrix.I need to declare the matrix as "Matrix" type so I can get its inverse directly by inv() function in Swix.

I need a matrix like this:

```
[[1.0,0.0,-0.85],
 [-0.425,1.0,0.0],
 [-0.425,0.85,1.0]]
```

I have tried this

```
var A=matrix(columns:3,rows:3)
A=[[1.0,0.0,-0.85],[-0.425,1,0],[-0.425,-0.85,1]]
```

How to do this? Also any other help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question, describe exactly what you want to achieve  and show what you have tried.

Comment: var A=matrix(columns:3,rows:3)
A=([1.0,0.0,-0.85],[-0.425,1,0],[-0.425,-0.85,1])

Answer (score 0):

Will it work if you create and array of arrays?

```
var a = [[Float]]()

a = [[1.0,0.0,-0.85],
     [-0.425,1.0,0.0],
     [-0.425,0.85,1.0]]

print (a[0][1]) // prints: 0.0
```

Comment: I need to declare it as a Matrix type so that I can get its inverse directly by using the inv() function